# Top DPS charts on trash in 5 man instances as Fire Mage

Tags: world-of-warcraft

On a single target, I have the rotation down to become an effective DPS caster on my Fire Mage. When it comes to instances though and trash mobs, I have a very difficult time and am usually in last place as per recount in DPS. Between Blizzard, Dragon's Breath, Flamestrike and Impact, I can't figure out the best method to top dps charts for trash in 5 man instances.

What's the current best rotation/method for doing it as a fire mage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire mages generate AoE DPS through propagating DoTs. Avoid using Dragon's Breath and even Blizzard.

Blast Wave (with attached Flamestrike) is a good opener. Then you want to focus on the largest target in the trash pack and hit it with Living Bomb and a good Fireball. You're hoping to quickly build the "magic triad" of DoTs: Ignite, Pyroblast and Living Bomb and then use an Impact proc'd Fire Blast. For longer trash packs, also use Combustion and then Fire Blast.

For smaller trash packs, simply spamming Blast Wave and Flame Strike is the way to go.

[Elitist Jerks Thread](http://elitistjerks.com/f75/t110326-cataclysm_fire_mage_compendium) for more Fire Mage goodness.